# How to speed-up the Ipopt solver?

Tags: python, numpy, mathematical-optimization, ipopt, cyipopt

I want to solve the following (relaxed, i.e. v(t) ∈ [0, 1]) optimal control problem with [cyipopt](https://github.com/mechmotum/cyipopt):

[image]

Here's what I have so far to solve the discretized problem:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cyipopt import minimize_ipopt
from scipy.optimize._numdiff import approx_derivative

# z = (x1(t0) .... x1(tN) x2(t0) .... x2(tN) v(t0) .... v(tN))^T

def objective(z, time):
    x0, x1, v = np.split(z, 3)
    res = 0.0
    for i in range(time.size-1):
        h = time[i+1] - time[i]
        res += h*((x0[i]-1)**2 + (x1[i]-1)**2)
    return res


def ode_rhs(t, x, v):
    x0, x1 = x
    xdot1 = x0 - x0*x1 - 0.4*x0*v
    xdot2 = -x1 + x0*x1 - 0.2*x1*v
    return np.array([xdot1, xdot2])


def constraint(z, time):
    x0, x1, v = np.split(z, 3)
    x = np.array([x0, x1])
    res = np.zeros((2, x0.size))

    # initial values
    res[:, 0] = x[:, 0] - np.array([0.5, 0.7])

    # 'solve' the ode-system
    for j in range(time.size-1):
        h = time[j+1] - time[j]
        # implicite euler scheme
        res[:, j+1] = x[:, j+1] - x[:, j] - h*ode_rhs(time[j+1], x[:, j+1], v[j])
    return res.flatten()


# time grid
tspan = [0, 12]
dt    = 0.1
time  = np.arange(tspan[0], tspan[1] + dt, dt)

# initial point
z0 = 0.1 + np.zeros(time.size*3)

# variable bounds
bnds = [(None, None) if i < 2*time.size else (0, 1) for i in range(z0.size)]

# constraints:
cons = [{
    'type': 'eq', 
    'fun': lambda z: constraint(z, time), 
    'jac': lambda z: approx_derivative(lambda zz: constraint(zz, time), z)
}]

# call the solver
res = minimize_ipopt(lambda z: objective(z, time), x0=z0, bounds=bnds, 
                     constraints=cons, options = {'disp': 5})
```

The code works as expected. However, it runs quite slow. Any ideas on how I can speed up the solver?

Comment: Have you used a line profiler to see where your code is running slow?

Comment: Often we fully discretize the problem so we don't need an ODE solver inside. That makes the problem (very) large and sparse, but that is what IPOPT is good at.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen That's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By analyzing Ipopt's output

```
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =     30.153
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =    203.782
```

we can see that the evaluation of your functions is the bottleneck. So let's try to profile your code as Tom suggested in the comments:

```
In [2]: %timeit objective(z0, time)
307 µs ± 6.96 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit constraint(z0, time)
1.38 ms ± 4.77 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Okay, not bad. But we can do better. As a rule of thumb, try to prevent loops in numerical python code whenever possible. You can find some best numpy practices e.g. in Jake VanderPlas awesome [talk at the PyCon2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEUXKG97YRw). Your objective is equivalent to:

```py
def objective(z, time):
    x0, x1, v = np.split(z, 3)
    h = time[1:] - time[:-1]
    return np.sum(h*((x0[1:]-1)**2 + (x1[1:]-1)**2))
```

Similarly, you can remove the loop inside your `constraint` function. Note that

```py
# 'solve' the ode-system
for j in range(time.size-1):
    h = time[j+1] - time[j]
    # implicite euler scheme
    res[:, j+1] = x[:, j+1] - x[:, j] - h*ode_rhs(time[j+1], x[:, j+1], v[j])
```

is the same as

```py
h = time[1:] - time[:-1]
res[:, 1:] = x[:, 1:] - x[:, :-1] - h * ode_rhs(time, x[:, 1:], v[:-1])
```

Timing the functions again, we get

```
In [4]: %timeit objective(z0, time)
31.8 µs ± 683 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit constraint(z0, time)
54.1 µs ± 647 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

i.e. speedups with factors 10x and 25x! Consequently, we can significantly reduce the solver runtime:

```
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =     30.906
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =     46.950
```

---

However, note that calculating the gradient and jacobian numerically by finite differences is still computationally expensive and prone to rounding errors:

```
In [6]: %timeit approx_derivative(lambda zz: objective(zz, time), z0)
232 ms ± 3.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [7]: %timeit approx_derivative(lambda zz: constraint(zz, time), z0)
642 ms ± 1.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Instead, we can go one step further and calculate both via algorithmic differentiation (AD) by means of the [jax](https://github.com/google/jax) library:

```py
from jax.config import config
# enable 64 bit floating point precision
config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)

import jax.numpy as np
from jax import grad, jacfwd, jit
```

Then, we only need to change the `constraint` function as follows:

```
def constraint(z, time):
    x0, x1, v = np.split(z, 3)
    x = np.array([x0, x1])
    res = np.zeros((2, x0.size))

    # initial values
    res = res.at[:, 0].set(x[:, 0] - np.array([0.5, 0.7]))
    h = time[1:] - time[:-1]
    res = res.at[:, 1:].set(x[:, 1:] - x[:, :-1] - h*ode_jit(time[1:], x[:, 1:], v[:-1]))
    return res.flatten()
```

since item assignments are not supported, see [here](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html). Next, we just-in-time (jit) compile the functions:

```
# jit the functions
ode_jit = jit(ode_rhs)
obj_jit = jit(lambda z: objective(z, time))
con_jit = jit(lambda z: constraint(z, time))

# Build and jit the derivatives
obj_grad = jit(grad(obj_jit))   # objective gradient
con_jac = jit(jacfwd(con_jit))  # constraint jacobian

# Dummy first call in order to compile the functions
print("Compiling the functions...")
_ = obj_jit(z0), con_jit(z0), obj_grad(z0), con_jac(z0)
print("Done.")
```

Timing again, we obtain

```
In [10]: %timeit obj_grad(z0)
62.1 µs ± 353 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit con_jac(z0)
204 µs ± 1.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

i.e. speedups with factors 3740x and 2260x. Finally, we can pass the exact gradient and jacobians:

```py
# constraints:
cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': con_jit, 'jac': con_jac}]

# call the solver
res = minimize_ipopt(obj_jit, x0=z0, jac=obj_grad, bounds=bnds,
                         constraints=cons, options={'disp': 5})
```

and obtain

```
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =     35.348
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      1.691
```